# Select part of InnerText using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

How can I select a part of InnerText using HtmlAgilityPack, for example:

```
<td class="playerName" width="192">
  <a href="/cricket/content/player/21585.html">player1</a>* 
</td>
```

Now I want to select `21585` from the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can get to the HREF with XPATH & code, like this

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(myHtmlFilePath);
    // get to the A tag using XPATH
    HtmlNode a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='playerName']/a");
    // get the HREF attribute
    string href = a.GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```

but not beyond. You'll have to parse the href manually, here is a quick hack that works with your example:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"dummy:" + href); // use whatever "drive-like" root
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri.LocalPath));
```